# Store value in Yes/No field in Access using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have an Access database with a Yes/No field. How can I update the Yes/No field value?

I tried

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + true ;
```

but it gave me the following error on "true":

```
Syntax error in query expression ''True';'.
```

Please advise me on the correct C# syntax.

Comment: you want a `BIT`, which stores a `1` or `0`, `true` or `false`

Comment: This is possibly a [tag:sql] question and not a `c#` one.

Comment: @NabeelHassanein here is where you can find all that you are looking for. 
[C# and Sql tips and tricks](http://www.google.com) also look at that statement I would think that even with normal `Sql UPDATE Statement` that one would provide a `WHERE` clause....

Comment: Are you saying to have to access a database or have an Access Database (ie Microsoft Access)?

Comment: I've edited your question. If you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back. To roll back an edit, click on the "edited ... ago" link. This will bring you to the page with the edit history, where you have buttons to roll back.

Comment: I have Access Database

Comment: to Aravol Yes Microsoft Access

Answer (score 2):

I can see a number of issues with your statement.

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + true ;
```

I don't have MS-Access handy, but it seems that it uses -1 for "Yes". So you could try:

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = -1" ;
```

or if the boolean value is in a variable, say, `foo`:

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + (foo ? -1 : 0) ;
```

This is not advised however, as commenter @Gord Thompson points out. A literal

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = True" ;
```

or

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + foo;
```

should work.

I notice that your error message reads

> Syntax error in query expression ''True';'.

with `True` between quotes, but also with a semicolon in there. It's possible that the line that causes the error is different from what you gave us, perhaps it was

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + true + ";";
```

or something like that? With a semicolon where SQL wasn't expecting one?

There are some more issues. I notice that both the table name and the column name are `ch1`. While it is allowed that a table and a column have the same name, it doesn't happen often. Are these really the right names?

Also, there is no WHERE clause here. In it's current form, this statement will fill the entire column of the table with the same value, which may not be what you want.

Finally, the format

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + something ;
```

is open to a well-known attack called SQL injection. You should read up on so-called "prepared statements" and use these. As a side benefit, this will also prevent some syntax errors in your SQL statements.

Comment: Yes, Access stores "Yes/No" fields internally as `-1` and `0`, but it is usually not a good idea to refer to typed data by its internal numeric representation. "Yes/No" fields in Access should almost always just be compared to (or SET to) `True` or `False`.

Comment: @GordThompson Makes sense. I don't have a copy of Access here, but.. would "UPDATE ch1 SET ch1 = True" be valid? Because the error message that the OP gets suggests it isn't.

Comment: Yes, `UPDATE myTable SET yesnoField = True` is valid in Access SQL. I could not actually recreate the issue in the question, so I don't really know what their problem is.

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson. I've edited that into my answer. I'm guessing the OP gave us the wrong code; probably an earlier or later version of the code where the error occurred.

Comment: Update T_Est SET  Est_ch1 = "+ true + ";";

Comment: Update T_Est SET Est_ch1 = "+ true;
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '0True'.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear, but I believe the field your searching for is a `bit` field.  The field will store either a *One* or *Zero*.  Which will represent a boolean:

- True or False
- Yes or No
- On or Off

For instance, hopefully this clarifies an approach for you.

Comment: @ja72 Actually, in an Access database `True` is represented internally as `-1`. However, it is usually not advisable to manipulate typed data using the underlying numeric representation, so a "Yes/No" field in Access should almost always just be compared to (or SET to) `True `or `False`.

Comment: as integer it is -1, but as a `bit` it is 1. So `-1=true=0x1b`

Comment: @ja72 Fair enough, but that's more or less my point. Access stores `True` values for `Yes/No` fields internally as Integer `-1`, and if we want to "think of" a `Yes/No` field as a `bit` field then that is actually (binary) `1`, but the fact remains that it is just a `Yes/No` field with two possible values: `True` and `False`.

Comment: Yes it is right what you said 0=false=off and 1=true=on

Answer (score 1):

Treat a YesNo field like a number field when updating using Access SQL.

Instead of

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + true ;
```

Write

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = true " ;
```

Or

```
string myBoolStr = "TRUE"
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = " + myBoolStr ;
```

In other words, Access SQL expects a string for numbers and booleans.
As strings, they go INSIDE the double quotes.
But, numeric and booleans are not single quoted inside the double quotes.

If chi were a string field, your query would be

```
string sQuery = @"UPDATE ch1 set ch1 = 'True'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making a program using Visual Studio 2012 in C# where I connect to a MS-Access 2010 database which has a table with a field named EnabledDisabled.  This field is a Yes/No Data Type(in other words you will see its format is True/False.  This type of field looks like a checkbox.  Anyway, from C# this is what I did and in order to set the field as checked=True=Yes it must be passed as Integer with -1 and in order to set it as unchecked=False=No it must be passed as Integer with 0.

```
string myConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\MYDATABASE.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

OleDbConnection myDBConnection = null;

int myEnabled = 0;

if (checkBox1.Checked == true)

{

   myEnabled = -1; // Set as checked or Yes in MS-Access on a Yes/No Data Type Field

   myComment+= ", Account=Enabled";

}

else

{

   myEnabled = 0; // Set as unchecked or No in MS-Access on a Yes/No Data Type Field

   myComment += ", Account=Disabled";

}

myDBConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);

myDBConnection.Open();

string myDateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

myDBCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into tblAuthorizedUsers (USERID, Fullname, AuthorizationLevel, EnabledDisabled, USERIDMaker, DateTimeStamp) values('" + textBox1.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "','" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "','" + myAuthorizationLevel + "','" + myEnabled + "','" + Environment.UserName.Trim().ToUpper() + "','" + myDateTimeStamp + "')", myDBConnection);

myDBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // With this you can handles multiple inserts to a MSAccess table even if this line is inside of the loop of multiple records handling
```